# University logo on left, down side on titling page

Tags: graphics

I am adding the university logo on the left side, all the way down on the titling page. But when I increase the size of the picture, it removes the already existing text to new blank page. 
I can see that there is a lot of space on the bottom of the page. But I can`t move the logo further down.
Tips?

This is the code in the titlingpage:

```
\title{Energy: \\Testing energy systems}

\author{authors xx} 

\date{Februar 01, 2019}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and } 

\renewcommand{\and}{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}

\topmargin

\begin{center}
    \line(1,0){415}\\ 
    [3mm]
    \huge{\textbf{Energy: \\Design of energy systems}} 
    \line(1,0){415}\\
    \textsc{\Large Energy}\\
    \textsc{\large School project}
\end{center}

\begin{figure}[H] %Frontpage picture
        \includegraphics[width=140mm, height=90mm]{Figurer/Vindtunnel.jpg}
        \centering  
\end{figure} %Frontpage picture

 \begin{figure}[b]        % THIS IS THE LOGO I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH
   \begin{flushleft}
     \includegraphics[width=70mm, height=20mm]{Figurer/ntnuloggis.pdf}
     \end{flushleft}
  \end{figure}             % THIS IS THE LOGO I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ l | l }
  \large{Trude Nervik}  & \large{Tormod Hansen} \\
  \large{Per Sandber} & \large{Nadia Nansen}
 \end{tabular}
\end{titlingpage}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post the (compilable) code you tried?

Comment: We need to know the document class and the necessary packages.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Energy: \\Testing energy systems}

\author{authors xx} 

\date{Februar 01, 2019}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\centering

\hrulefill

{\huge\textbf{Energy: \\Design of energy systems}\\}

\hrulefill

\vfill

{\Large\textsc{Energy}\\}
{\large\textsc{School project}\\}

\vfill

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}

\vfill

{\large\begin{tabular}{ l | l }
Trude Nervik & Tormod Hansen \\
Per Sandber  & Nadia Nansen
\end{tabular}}

\vfill

\raggedright

\includegraphics[height=20mm]{example-image}

\end{titlingpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few points to note:

1. there's no rule that states `\includegraphics` must be in a `figure` environment.
2. `\large` and similar commands *don't* take an argument: they're declaration only limited by the scope in which they appear.
3. `\topmargin` is not a spacing command, but a parameter holding a dimension.
4. It makes little sense to specify both `width` and `height` for an image, as it would distort it.
5. Don't guess dimensions: `\line(1,0){415}` has an arbitrary length that may or may not fit; similarly, `width=140mm` is very dubious.